# IUP tree, Lua, how to walk/search tree structure

Tags: lua, iup

I'm using IUP with Lua. I want to store some data in the IUP tree structure.
So now the problem is, how can I search the tree to see if a certain entry already exists?

Unfortunately, the node titles of the tree only seem to be accessible by using

```
mytree.title1
mytree.title2
```

and so on.

It would be easy if the nodes were accessible by something like

```
 mytree.title(1)
 mytree.title(2)
```

Then I could just use a for loop. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table field names are just string keys, so you can put them together algorithmically.

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  print(mytree['title' .. i])
end
```

Look up [`string.format`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format) if you need to format the number into the field name in some non-default way.